# Is insulation blockinng airflow of my vented soffit?

Tags: insulation, attic, air-quality

I have insulation shoved in front of my vented soffit's should the insulation Be there It was already there when we moved I didn't think much of an till I started doing some research after I blew in more insulation and I blew it all the way to the decking should I pull this  installation out or leave it in?

Answer (score 1):

Attic ventilation is very important so make sure you pull away the insulation from the soffits. 
Purchase a small rake, a respirator and some quality gloves and do it before it’s the summer and the attic is now 40 degrees hotter than today. 
Depending on the climate zone, soffits are an important piece on attic ventilation.  They reduce the chance of ice dams, keep moisture down which prevents mold growth and help to keep the attic cooler in the summer. 
I removed mold covered insulation for the past several weekends, in researching this link was beneficial to me.

[PDF describing attic ventilation](http://www.airvent.com/pdf/literature/PAVbooklet.pdf)

For safety get a quality respirator and wear long sleeves, goggles and gloves.
I also suggest old rain jacket with a hood.  Fiberglass, dust and mold are small and can get everywhere easily and quickly.